# Do I need to write any closing code for NLog?

Tags: c#, nlog

I've just started using `NLog`.

I'm wondering I don't need to write any closing code (such as `Logger.Close();`). Do I need to?

I've already checked several blog posts (in Japanese), [NLog's GitHub project wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki), and [nlog-project.org](https://nlog-project.org/).

Comment: No you don`t :) Much better learning experience for you would be to try and write some POC application, check how it behaves. And if you want to ask some more specific and deep question, eg. when to run something like this or why it is available in the first place - this will be a much better question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NLog` will try to flush automatically on shutdown, but depending on platform then it might not always work.

For perfect result then you should call this just before application-exit:

```
NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
```

See also: [Wiki: Remember to flush](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#5-remember-to-flush)